# How to prove that $\lim_{x \to \infty}\int^{x+1}_x\frac {t^2+1}{t^2 + 20t + 8}dt=1$?

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\int^{x+1}_x\frac {t^2+1}{t^2 + 20t + 8}dt=1$$

This was in a multiple choice question, I managed to disprove all choices except this one which was the answer, I wonder how can I prove it formally (or atleast without relying on intuition that on $x \to \infty$ the integrand goes to $1$ , so the area of the rectangle is somehwat $1\times 1=1$). 
Appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$
\frac{{t^2  + 1}}{{t^2  + 20t + 8}} < \frac{{t^2  + 1}}{{t^2  + 1}} = 1
$$
and
$$
\frac{{t^2  + 1}}{{t^2  + 20t + 8}} = 1 - \frac{{20t + 7}}{{t^2  + 20t + 8}} > 1 - \frac{{20}}{t}
$$
for all $t>0$.

Answer (score 0):

The function
$$f:t\mapsto \frac{t^2+1}{t^2+20t+8}$$ is increasing on $[2,\infty )$.

Therefore $$f(x)\leq f(t)\leq f(x+1),$$
for all $x\leq t\leq x+1$. Hence $$f(x)\leq \int_{x}^{x+1}f(t)\,\mathrm d t\leq f(x+1).$$
Taking $x\to \infty $ gives the wished result.